# (NASM, C)Why would you need to malloc twice to create an array as shown here

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, nasm

```
char** names=(char**)malloc(count*sizeof(char*));
//while loop
names[count]=(char*)malloc(size+1);//why malloc again?
```

So `char** names=(char**)malloc(count*sizeof(char*));`  creates a pointer to a location hosting `4 times count` bytes and then stores pointer location to names?

Then in the while loop, `size+1` bytes long memory is allocated and its address is given to `names[count]`, which refers to the location pointed to by `names`? So here the memory created from the first malloc stores the location of memory created by the second malloc? And is the size of memory pointer 4 bytes, so that I can access each `names[count]` by moving to the next 4 bytes starting from the start of the memory location?

If my thinking is correct, are these correct NASM implementations of these two lines of c code:

```
;char** names=(char**)malloc(count*sizeof(char*));
  mov eax, dword count
  ;lea ebx, [eax*4]
  imul ebx, eax, 4
  push ebx
  call _malloc
  mov names, eax
  add esp, 4

;names[count]=(char*)malloc(size+1);
  mov ebx, size
inc ebx
push ebx
call _malloc
add esp,4
mov ebx, names
mov ecx, dword count
mov [ebx+ecx*4], eax
```

Fyi, also, these two lines of code are part of the following c code to extract names from a file and sort them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char path[]="names.txt";

  char szName[50];

  int count=0;

  int size=0;

  int x=0;
  int y=0;

  char* temp=0;
  int pos=0;

  FILE* file=fopen(path,"rt");

  if (file){

  while (!feof(file)){

  fscanf(file,"%50s",szName);
  count++;


  }

  }
  else{
       printf("Error opening file\n");
       return 1;
  }

  printf ("Count: %d\n",count);

  char** names=(char**)malloc(count*sizeof(char*));

  rewind(file);

  count=0;



  while (!feof(file)){

  fscanf(file,"%50s",szName);

  size=strlen(szName);

  names[count]=(char*)malloc(size+1);

  strcpy(names[count],szName);

  count++;


  }

  printf("Original file\n");

  for (x=0;x<count;x++){

  printf("Name %d:\t%s\n",x+1,names[x]);

  }


  for (x=0;x<count;x++){

  temp=names[x];
  pos=x;

  for (y=x;y<count;y++){

      if (strcmp(temp,names[y])>0){

      temp=names[y];
      pos=y;

      }    
  }

  temp=names[x];
  names[x]=names[pos];
  names[pos]=temp;    
  }

  printf("Sorted names\n");

  for (x=0;x<count;x++){

  printf("Name %d:\t%s\n",x+1,names[x]);

  }

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not do `names[count]=(char*)malloc(size+1);`. It is out-of-bound access.

Comment: It's part of working code given by my instructor. I will post the code in the op.

Comment: Working? It seems **happened** to work. It is considered as dangerous, so do not execute the code!

Comment: Your instructor is teaching you to write bad code. Want a dynamic array with two levels of indirection? `char (*array)[y] = malloc(x * sizeof *array);`... Want three levels of indirection? `char (*array)[y][z] = malloc(x * sizeof *array);`... As you can see, **there is no need for multiple `malloc`s to produce an array**, and in fact using multiple `malloc`s is wrong. **An array is a contiguous block of memory, in a single allocation**, and most functions rely upon this. **Using multiple `malloc`s breaks quite a few standard functions in serious ways**.

Comment: Okay I won't use it, but please still help me understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Why do you want to understand broken and/or unnecessary logic? Just get a new professor (one that's less broken and/or unnecessary)...

Comment: How about asking to the instructor who gave the code?

Comment: Additionally, you should not try to understand C as though it corresponds with a series of machine code instructions. C is described in terms of an *abstract machine*, which gives credibility to what @MikeCAT said earlier regarding the dangers of undefined behaviour. Your *physical machine* may have given that *undefined behaviour* a definition, but that isn't required to be the same definition for all machines, or even the same definition on your machine at a different time.

Comment: @Seb I you are using a library which cannot handle an array of dynamically allocated strings, then you may want to start looking for a new library.

Comment: @JefferyThomas You may want to start writing a new library...

Comment: I'm very sorry. I missed the `count=0;`. It won't be such a serious problem. By the way, they say `!feof(file)` won't work well and you should use `fscanf(file,"%50s",szName)==1` to tell whether it read some data. Also they say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your professor is creating an array of strings. The code as written is unnecessarily confusing, but the idea is sound.

Here is a *hopefully* less confusing example

```
// copy an existing string just like strdup()
char* stringDuplicate(const char* string) {
    size_t size = strlen(string) + 1; // 1 additional for `\0` terminator
    char* result = (char*)malloc(size * (sizeof(char)));
    strcpy(result, string);
    return result;
}

// copy an existing string array
char** stringArrayDuplicate(const char** stringArray, size_t size) {
    // Allocate an array which can hold size number of strings
    char** result = (char**)malloc(size * sizeof(char *));

    // For each string in stringArray, copy the string
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        result[i] = stringDuplicate(stringArray[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The main problem I have with this answer is the reference to "array of strings". Unfortunately it is a significant problem, because it's not uncommon for conflicting definitions of "string" to get in the way of a correct understanding of the C standard library. **edit**: I'm also not fond of explicit `void *` casts, particularly of the return value of `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

> So `char** names=(char**)malloc(count*sizeof(char*));` creates a pointer to a location
>   hosting `4 times count` bytes and then stores pointer location to names?

Yes, if `sizeof(char*)` in your environment is `4`.

> Then in the while loop, `size+1` bytes long memory is allocated and its address is given to
>   `names[count]`, which refers to the location pointed to by names?

The formar part is correct, but the latter is wrong.
The address is given to `count` elements ahead from the location pointed to by `names`.

> So here the memory created from the first malloc stores the location of memory created by the second malloc?

Yes, it does.

> And is the size of memory pointer 4 bytes,

It depends on the environment.

> so that I can access each names[count] by moving to the next 4 bytes starting from the start of the memory location?

Yes, if `sizeof(char*)` in your environment is `4`.

> If my thinking is correct, are these correct NASM implementations of these two lines of c code:

I found no error in the code, if `int` is a 32-bit integer in your environment.

Comment: _"The address is given to count elements ahead from the location pointed to by names, which is out-of-range."_ `count` is reset to zero before the second loop, so when are you suggesting that `count` will be out of bounds?

Comment: @Michael I was wrong and I missed the `count=0;`. I'm very sorry.

Comment: so with the first malloc let's say 8 bytes are allocated: 00000000. Then with the second two 4 bytes are allocated and their addresses are stored in above as follows: 11112222, where 1111 is the address of the location of the  first 4 byte memory.